# I got a job offer from Germany. What now?

Tags: germany, paperwork, working-visas

I have been offered a job in Germany and I have received the employment contract as well. I am a software engineer and I have the complete transcript with a stamp which states **degree completed**.

Would this suffice as a proof of my education or do I need the actual degree? Because applying for a formal degree takes more than 2 months and I don't have that much time.

Comment: This is not a travel question. Ask your future employer what they would accept.

Comment: @InsanityRules, his employer has already accepted. Now the question is what he needs to get a residence permit. Many countries have points systems where a degree gives points, but Germany goes by salary instead -- if someone pays him €40k or €50k a year, he must be highly qualified..

Comment: Two questions: a) What nationality / resident are you and b) does "job" mean "employment" or "contract work"?

Answer (score 1):

Ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange.

But summarized, Germany offers [Blue Card](http://www.bamf.de/EN/Migration/Arbeiten/BuergerDrittstaat/BlaueKarte/blaue-karte-node.html) work visa to highly skilled workers, and that is defined by earning enough money.

Comment: If it will be not enough money for getting Blue Card, then one should apply for regular residence permit for working purposes.